# Grails Quartz Plugin: Call service from cron (Session = NULL)

Tags: session, grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

Hey i have the following problem.

I have a service "a" with is called from a controller and works perfectly.

PROBLEM: When i call the same service from a cron the service can not find the session object.

**CRON JOB**

```
@Transactional
class TESTCLASS{

    def javax.sql.DataSource dataSource
    def sessionFactory

    static triggers = {
      cron name: 'TESTCLASS', cronExpression: "0 07  23 * * ?"
    }

    def execute() {
        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
        CrawlerService crawler = new CrawlerService()
        crawler.updatePagesWithoutCount(s)
    }
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
@Transactional
class CrawlerService {

def updatePagesWithoutCount(Session s){

    if(session==null){println ">>>> SESSION = NULL"}
    else{println ">>>> SESSION OK: "+session.toString()}
        //get all entries without count yet
```

before even the demotext is printed the method fails

```
Error |
2014-08-16 23:07:00,132 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
   Line | Method
->> 111 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   202 | run     in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run . . in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  29 | $tt__execute in twagocrawler.UpdatePagesWithoutCountJob
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   104 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
|   202 | run . . in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run     in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
```

Any ideas? how do I get access to the session in the service? By the way the session is accessible in the cron-job i can easily use it there. Also the sessionFactory object is null in the service.

Would really appriciate any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of the service before you're calling it:

```
CrawlerService crawler = new CrawlerService()
crawler.updatePagesWithoutCount(s)
```

So, that would not get the Spring dependency injection stuff. Have you tried just doing a:

```
def crawlerService
```

at the top of your Job class? That should make it such that the CrawlerService is injected properly.

Also, I noticed that you're passing in the session as a parameter to updatePagesWithoutCount, but then you never do anything with that passed in variable inside of the service method.